# CSS3 dropdown not staying open from whitespace between li and ul

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover, pseudo-element

I am making a CSS3 drop down menu for a company and have ran into a slight problem. I first figured the problem was being caused by wordpress but after recreating the nav in a jsfiddle I know it's something else.

I have a `nav` with two sub menus, on the sub menu I used a pseudo before element to give it a triangle on the top. It's a nice effect and  after I was testing it I found a problem. It functions great and really looks smooth but the white space between the `li` and `ul` is causing a rather large problem, if you hover between that white space the sub menu will close because it is not on the `li` hover state.

I am pretty good with css and have tried a lot of options but they all cause the same problem. Anyone have any ideas? I would rather not get ride of that design element but if I have to I will or should I use jQuery?

**CSS**

```
#top-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
}

#top-menu > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
}

  #top-menu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  width: 11.1%;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#top-menu > ul > li:hover {
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
}

#top-menu > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background: mediumSeaGreen;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px #2b2b2b;
}

#top-menu ul li ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid mediumSeaGreen;
  top: -10px;
  left: 42%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1002;
}

#top-menu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

#top-menu > ul > li > ul > li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #2b2b2b;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/48NrT/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place a transparent `:after` element behind the `:before` element. It's not how `:after` is suppose to be used, but it works quite well it seems

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/48NrT/6/)

```
#top-menu ul li ul:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:-10px;
    left:0px;
    height:10px;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    z-index:1001;
}
```

Comment: You are the man!! I could not find anything that would even resemble this problem. Also no one but you has bothered to help so I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help! On a side note you might want to create a fallback for browsers that don't support pseudo elements. That could be a problem depending on who you want it to reach

Comment: Yeah I have started to plan this out because I'm sure, after meeting the clients, they still use IE cave man edition.. lol I will never understand how anyone tech savvy or not would ever consider using IE. Maybe it is just me but once again thank you so much man.